# how to calculate Entropy from series of outcome?

Tags: math, statistics

I want to generate my own private key with dice and/or other very entropic phenomenon. But how can I calculate if my data have a good entropy ? I mean if I throw dice in a certain way too much time maybe my outcome will not be trully random, maybe my dice is not a very good dice and have imperfection etc.

So can I just throw it 300+ and if I don't have 0.166666% each result (1,2,3,4,5,6) it's not good ?

Also I want to write my own series of dice result just to compare how deficient is my brain when I try to generate true randomness.

Thanks

Comment: This seems more a questions for statistics SE or mathemticals SE site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a statistics question unrelated to Bitcoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the an open source program called **[ent](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/)**. Here are the results for rolling a die six times with the result vector of <666666>.

**% echo -n "666666" | ./ent**

Entropy = 0.000000 bits per byte.

Optimum compression would reduce the size
of this 6 byte file by 100 percent.

Chi square distribution for 6 samples is 1530.00, and randomly
would exceed this value less than 0.01 percent of the times.

Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 54.0000 (127.5 = random).
Monte Carlo value for Pi is 4.000000000 (error 27.32 percent).
Serial correlation coefficient is undefined (all values equal!).

Answer (score 0):

You may find this old thread on bitcointalk helpful -> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=24268.0

There are 2^160 possible addresses in Bitcoin. To put that in perspective there's an estimated 2^63 grains of sand on all of Earth's beaches, [citation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213194957/http://www.hawaii.edu/suremath/jsand.html).

If you have a die and roll it 99 times, you have 6^99 different possible combinations. The number of different possible outcomes is [so large](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E99) that even with a dice that has imperfections causing less entropy the likelyhood of someone else rolling the same 99 numbers is astronomically unfeasible.